# Converting a Case Transform in ADF Mapping DataFlow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am currently building a DF in ADF where i am converting the below Query which is already placed in another ETL tool called BigDecission. The Query looks like below

```
SELECT
    Asset_ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN meter = 'LTPC' THEN reading_date ELSE NULL END) AS LTPC_Date,
    MAX(CASE WHEN meter = 'LTPC' THEN page_Count ELSE NULL END) AS LTPC,
  
FROM
    mv_latest_asset_read
GROUP BY
    Asset_ID
```

While converting this piece in ADF DF i have used AGGREGATE transform and done GROUP BY "ASSET_ID" .
In the AGGREGATES Tab i am deriving the column "LTPC_DATE" and "LTPC" with below mentioned code.

LTPC_DATE ---- > max(case(METER=='LTPC',READING_DATE))
[image]

LTPC ---- > max(case(METER=='LTPC',PAGE_COUNT))
[image]

But in the output i am getting null values which shouldn't be the case. Can anyone identify the right way to do it.

Comment: could you please add your sample source data and expected result?

Comment: Try the aggregate expression with maxIf() instead of max with a case statement: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expressions-usage#maxif

Answer (score 1):

I followed the same approach to reproduced above and getting proper result.

Please check the below:

**My source data:**

[image]

Here I have taken 2 additional columns using derived column transformation and giving a sample value.

[image]

**Group By and aggregate:**

[image]

Used `max(case(condtion,expression))` here.

[image]

**Result in Data preview:**

[image]

Try to check your projection in the source. Also, transform this to a sink file and check if it gives correct result or not.

If it still gives same, you can try `maxIf(condition, expression)` as suggested by **@Mark Kromer MSFT**.

[image]

The above also giving the same result for me.

**If your source is a database, you can try query option in the source** of dataflow and give the above query.

[image]

After Importing projection, you can see the desired result in the Data preview.

[image]